# Shrink content in flexbox in fullscreen on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, viewport

I'm using flexbox on three divs, a holder which contains content and menu div, to vertically fill the screen when using the fullscreen api (simplified example below).  It works just fine however I have a `min-height: 400px;` limitation on the content div and when viewed landscape on a mobile the content div is too large and scrolls.  I can't change the min-height, it's controlled elsewhere and has to stay.  Is there a way to shrink the content to that it fits in the available height?  Perhaps some sort of `* { }` CSS that might work or a javascript work around?

I've tried using the viewport meta tag and setting initial-scale to values between 1.0 and 10.0 but nothing changed above 1.0.  And I've also tried `transform:scaleY();` which was inaccurate and not visually good.

```css
.holder:fullscreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- holder -->
<div class="holder">

  <!-- content -->
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <!-- content -->

  <!-- menu -->
  <div class="menu">menu</div>
  <!-- menu -->

</div>
```

Comment: Can't you override the `min-height` with `min-height:0 !important`?

Comment: Nope that's not the issue.  A third party api for a canvas based app is embedded into the content div and it has a min-height set to make sure all the buttons on the interface are visible.  Any smaller and they overlap.  Going below 400px would mean modifying it's whole interface, all it's buttons etc.